# R: how to create a binary matrix with columns from largest number of ones to least

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to obtain a binary matrix that contains all possible combinations of N zeros or ones (for any N). The matrix should be ordered according to the number of ones. For example, for N=4, the matrix should look like

```
1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

For very large N, I'd like to be able to just compute the first 1000 (or so) columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid` to generate the full matrix, and `order` to sort it according to the number of ones. Here is a function that does this and that lets you print the result up to a maximum number of columns.

```
bin.matrix <- function(N, max.cols){
  cbs <- unname(as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),N))))
  cbs <- cbs[rev(order(rowSums(cbs))),]
  max.cols <- ifelse(missing(max.cols),nrow(cbs),max.cols)
  t(cbs[1:max.cols,])
}

bin.matrix(6,max.cols=10)
# > bin.matrix(6,max.cols=10)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0    0     1
# [2,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1     0
# [3,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1     1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1     1
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    1    1     1
```

Note that the function generates *all* combination and then merely reduces the amount that's printed. There may be more efficient solutions for larger `N`.